# vscode aliases "Go To definition" fail on huge project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code, aliases

I have a huge project for the more than 4000 modules and of course, we using webpack aliases:

```
appAliases: {
   components: resolveApp('src/components'),
   features: resolveApp('src/features'),
   core: resolveApp('src/core'),
   api: resolveApp('src/api'),
   store: resolveApp('src/app-store/store'),
   images: resolveApp('src/images'),
   constants: resolveApp('src/constants'),
   fonts: resolveApp('src/fonts'),
   extensions: resolveApp('src/extensions'),
   localization: resolveApp('src/localization'),
   'app-router': resolveApp('src/app-router'),
   'app-store': resolveApp('src/app-store'),
   'unit-test-mocks': resolveApp('src/unit-test-mocks'),
```

},

each folder at the root has file `index.js` with content

`export * from './my-awesome-component
export * from './my-second-awesome-component`

Furthermore, each nested component also includes `index.js` which probably exports main-component file

nested index.js to component level

`export * from './my-awesome-component'`

and so on, at the core of root there main exports.

And vsCode stucking while handling such exports and go-to-definition break

I cannot navigate to deeply nested components
I've been tried several vscode configs the latest one is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "checkJs": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "core/*": ["src/core/*"],
      "api/*": ["src/api/*"],
      "store/*": ["src/app-store/store/*"],
      "images/*": ["src/images/*"],
      "constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "fonts/*": ["src/fonts/*"],
      "extensions/*": ["src/extensions/*"],
      "localization/*": ["src/localization/*"],
      "app-router/*": ["src/app-router/*"],
      "app-store/*": ["src/app-store/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: the config you show us is a `tsconfig` file. Nothing to do with `vscode` configs ?

Comment: it's jsconfig.json

Comment: samething, anyway i don't understand what you mean by ''can't navigate to deeply nested components''